# Can someone help? I'm trying to make a programs that loops through numbers -1to10 and makes circles with the radius squared but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

I want the program to loop trough each number in the for loop and create a circle with the radius of that number squared but it doesn't seem to work. I only creates a circle with the radius of the last number in the for loop.

I've tried creating a separate function and return the value and putting into my draw function, but that didn't seem to  work.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  for (i = -1; i <= 10; i++) {
    newI = i ** 2;
  };
  background(250);
  circle(300, 300, newI);
//ignore the lines those are just the axis//
  line(300, 0, 300, 600);
  line(0, 300, 600, 300);
}
```

I want each new radius of each new circle to be that of the number in the for loop squared.

Comment: For starters, those calls to `circle()` and `line()` probably belong _inside_ the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tim Biegeleisen - the circle() and line() should be in the loop, but another approach is to have them separate.

Rather than putting the logic into the loop - have the loop iteration call a separate named frunction and pass the new i value as the argument.

EDIT: loop changed to decrement in order to reverse the order of radius.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  for (i = 10; i >= -1; i--) {
    createCircle(i ** 2)
  };

}


function createCircle(newI){
  background(250);
  circle(300, 300, newI);
  line(300, 0, 300, 600);
  line(0, 300, 600, 300);
}
```

Comment: i tried running this and it ended up the same, just one circle.

Comment: are you sure that a) you are not removing and redrawing the circle each iteration of hte loop? or b) that you are not drawing the circle at the same co-ordinates so there is actually all 10 circles - but each is sitting directly over its predecessors?

Comment: you are probably right about the second one. they're all probably on top of each other. how do i make them "see through"?

Comment: Try running your loop from largest to smallest radiius

Comment: EDIT - I just changed the loop to reverse the order as suggested in the comments.

Comment: damn. now i just prints the first circle.

Comment: i figured out the problem. like you said i had to put the circle function in the for loop